# CreateBanner method not working

Tags: android, ios, sdk, unity-game-engine, revmob

When calling `CreateBanner ()` nothing happens on the iOS platform. No SDK callbacks are being invoked.

```
...
RevMob instance = RevMob.Start (applicationIDs, GameObjectName);
...

void LoadBannerWithDefaultSize ()
{
#if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE)
    banner = instance.CreateBanner ();
#endif
}
```

NOTE: When running on an Android device, one of the next callbacks are always invoked:

```
// IRevMobListener

public void AdDidReceive (string revMobAdType) {}
public void AdDidFail (string revMobAdType) {}
```

I have just followed all RevMob configuration steps from the Unity SDK documentation:
http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/unity.html#configuration

Any hints?

Using:

- RevMob 7.2.7
- Unity3D 4.3.4

Comment: The game object must be created and alive forever, i.e. a call to `DontDestroyOnLoad` after instantiation is necessary. In order to see the banner you have to call the `Show` method.

Comment: Hi Kay, thank you for your comment. I am calling `DontDestroyOnLoad` on my `gameObject` and also guarantying a single instance of it during all game scenes. The strange thing is that on the Android platform everything is working (Banners and Fullscreens callbacks are being invoked) while on the iOS platform only the `CreateFullscreen ()` callbacks are being invoked. I really need to know when an iOS Banner gets loaded also by listening from both `AdDidReceive (...)` or `AdDidFail (...)`.

Comment: I use 7.2.4 on iOS only. I noticed in RevMob.cs that `CreateBanner ()` seems to be different on the two platforms. In my code I call the other variant with expicit parameters:   `CreateBanner (0, 0, Screen.width*0.5f, null, null)`. Maybe you should give this a try

Comment: Actually I am using both `CreateBanner ()` and `CreateBanner (x, y, w, h, null, null)` methods:

    public void LoadBanner ()
    {
    #if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE) && !UNITY_EDITOR
        if (BannerRect == null)
            LoadBannerWithDefaultSize ();
        else
            LoadBannerWithCustomBannerRectSize (BannerRect);
    #endif
    }

Maybe I should try to downgrade my RevMob SDK version to 7.2.4. Thank you for your comment again @Kay.